# I saw some code in "return" that i don't understand. Can somebody help me?

Tags: c, return

Is there any doc i can read about this kind of function?

```
// return the capital of char c
char a(char c){
    return c >= 'a' && c<='z' ?
           c +'A' - 'a':c;
}
```

Comment: its called ternary operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the ternary operator.  :)  And then it will be clear the code is doing:

```
if (c >= 'a' && c<='z') {
   return(c +'A' - 'a');
} else {
    return c;
}
```

So basically it is capitalizing the Latin alphabet in ASCII.

Comment: It's **badly** capitalizing the Latin alphabet.  Letters are not guaranteed to be represented contiguously.  See Section 5.2.1 of the C Standard:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: the code will properly capitalize the ASCII characters in the range 'a'...'z'

Comment: @user3629249 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC  There is no requirement that letters in a character set be represented sequentially.  Code that depends on such a detail is **bad** code.

Comment: Andrew: I updated my answer to clarify that this only works for ASCII.